# Как растянуть яндекс-карты на всю высоту экрана?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, css

```
height:100% не работает
```

Например ширина 650px, наверху есть какой-то контент, и чтобы снизу карты пустота не оставалась, хочу чтобы в высоту карта заполняла пустое пространство.

Comment: height: 100% работает только когда у родительского элемента выставлен height

Comment: Я у всех родительских элементов выставил 100%
Ни одного пикселя в высоту не появляется все равно.

Answer (score 1):

Яндекс незнаю, вот пример с гугл.мэпс, делал недавно:

http://jsfiddle.net/KW3U7/

Если нужны управляющие конструкции карт: то у #mapid, сделайте:

```
#mapid { width: 100%; height 100%; margin: 0; }
```

Comment: Может с помощью функции вычислить высоту монитора, вычесть высоту контента сверху, и вставить это в css?

Comment: можно и так, что бы не смущать пользователей без JS (а то они любят морщится когда "декорация" контента осуществляется при помощи скриптов) напомню, что само использование maps предполагает наличие включенного JS ;) или ещё пару способов 1) Накатите высоту блока с контентом в % 2) задайте ему "позишн: абсолют;", вот пример:  http://jsfiddle.net/alpha9000/g63j7/1/

Comment: У меня всё хорошо с JS, я вычисляю высоту окна, но про карту никак не догодался, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте для начала, чтобы страница на все окно была, и убрать `padding` и `margin`:

```css
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}  

#map{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div id='map' style='background: green; color: white'>
Map
</div>
</body>
</html>
```